# Integration is a Linear Transform so what is the Matrix representation of the antiderivative?

Tags: integration, matrices, linear-transformations

I understand integration is a linear transform and linear transforms can be denoted/written as a matrix. Then as I understand it, integration (and differentiation) can be written as matrix multiplication where the matrix operates on a vector of coefficients of a polynomial. If this is the case, what is the general form of a matrix that represents integration/antidifferentiation? I'd love to know if I'm misunderstanding something here!

Comment: A linear transformation is determined by its action on a basis. So, suppose $T:P_n(\Bbb{R})\to P_{n+1}(\Bbb{R})$ is given by integrating. So, what is $T(1),T(x),T(x^2),\dots, T(x^n)$? Calculate these outputs and arrange the results in a nice matrix (of course here I'm calculating relative to the "usual basis" of the space of polynomials).

Comment: Linear transformations of **finite-dimensional** vector spaces can be represented by matrices. So you can't expect some “general form of a matrix”, since function spaces are often infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @HansLundmark I understand but many integration problems should be writable as matrix. Your point is a great addition though. Since there's no infinite-dimensional case I think the focus of this question can still (valuably) be on finite dimensional cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your attempt to solve the question, here's some corrections. Let us fix an $n\in\Bbb{N}$, and let $P_n(\Bbb{R})$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$. We consider the indefinite integration as a mapping $T:P_n(\Bbb{R})\to P_{n+1}(\Bbb{R})$ (and for simplicity suppose we do not add any constant of integration; or more specifically, $T\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\right):=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$). Let $\sigma_n=\{1,x,\dots, x^n\}$ and $\sigma_{n+1}:=\{1,x,\dots, x^{n+1}\}$ be the "usual bases". Note that it is important to specify the domain and target space, and also the respective bases being used, because all of these will affect the matrix.

Now, I'm sure you'll agree that
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
T(1)=x &= 0\cdot (1) + 1\cdot (x) + 0 \cdot (x^2)+\dots + 0\cdot (x^n)+ 0 \cdot (x^{n+1})\\
T(x)=\frac{x^2}{2} &= 0\cdot (1) + 0\cdot (x) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot (x^2) + \cdots + 0\cdot (x^n)+0 \cdot (x^{n+1})\\
\vdots\\
T(x^n)=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 0\cdot (1) + 0\cdot (x) + 0\cdot (x^2) + \cdots 0\cdot (x^n)+
\frac{1}{n+1} \cdot (x^{n+1})
\end{cases}
\end{align}
When writing down the associated matrix $[T]_{\sigma_n}^{\sigma_{n+1}}$, we only write down the coefficients appearing above (i.e the stuff before the brackets). So,
\begin{align}
[T]_{\sigma_n}^{\sigma_{n+1}}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\
1 & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0& \frac{1}{2} & \cdots &0\\
\vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
It's a good idea to write this out explicitly without any $\cdots$ for $n=3,4,5$ so you get the idea.

Finally, note that you cannot apply $T$ to the function $\exp$, because $\exp$ is NOT a polynomial so it doesn't even lie in the vector space $P_n(\Bbb{R})=\text{domain}(T)$, and of course, you can never apply a function to something which is not in its domain.

Having said this, I should mention that we can consider the vector space $V=C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$ of infinitely differentiable functions $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, and consider the mapping $S:V\to V$ which takes an $f\in V$ and gives an antiderivative $S(f)$; for example
\begin{align}
S(f)(x):= \int_0^xf(t)\,dt.
\end{align}
This is a perfectly well-defined linear-transformation, and for example,
\begin{align}
S(\exp)(x)&:=\int_0^xe^t\,dt = e^x-1.
\end{align}
The only thing is that now $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, so it doesn't make sense to speak of matrices; matrices are only defined for linear transformations between finite-dimensional spaces (with a specific choice of basis).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is so helpful. Could you elaborate on the infinite-dimensional part? If $T$ is some (n+1)xn matrix for any n degree polynomial, why can't we inductively find an infinite-dimensional matrix for an infinite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: @Bennet Leff here's thr thing about induction: it only tells you what happens for a natural number (which is of course finite by definition). You cannot just say "it's true for all natural numbers by induction and therefore it is true for $n=\infty$". This is just plain wrong, because once you get to infinity, this is already outside the realm of induction. Another thing I should mention: a matrix is nothing more than a convenient (though sometimes confusing) way of organising information about the linear map. But don't be fooled: what you really care about is the linear map, not the matrix.

Comment: another thing: you use the term "infinite dimensional matrix" but you'll see that if you try to properly define such a term, then really it amounts to nothing more than a function (from a certain index set into the field). of course once the index set gets infinite, you can't may all of this information as a square array of numbers anymore.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying and all the help here :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I thought I understood but peek-a-boo was kind enough to explain to me with corrections below. Thanks to peek-a-boo I've got it! At least in some simple form. I'm not sure exactly how this applies to functions like $exp$, though one could apply this technique to the series expansion.

For an example of anti-differentiation of polynomials of degree 2 with coefficients: $$a, b, c \\ a + bx + cx^2$$ set up a matrix as such:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  k&0&0\\
  x&0&0\\
  0&x^2 \over 2&0\\
  0&0&x^3 \over 3\\
\end{array}
\right] * \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 a\\b\\c\\0
\end{array}
\right]$$
Then the resultant vector of coefficients will be:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 ak\\ax\\bx^2 \over 2\\cx^3 \over 3
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Not quite right. There should be no $x$ in the matrices, just the *coefficients* with respect to whatever bases you are using.

Comment: @HansLundmark I'm not sure I follow. I put this into a matrix multiplier online to test out and it seems to fit with my understanding. Could you submit an answer to this question to clarify in more detail?